# Non-Unique ID's When Creating Form Elements for the Same Name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following line in a form I'm building in Rails:

```
<%= text_field_tag "new_receipt[]", nil -%>
<%= text_field_tag "new_receipt[]", nil -%>
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="new_receipt[]" id="new_receipt_">
<input type="text" name="new_receipt[]" id="new_receipt_">
```

The problem is the id's for both these boxes are the same.  What's the best way to get rails to create a unique ID?

I could do

```
<%= text_field_tag "new_receipt[]", nil, id: "new_receipt_1" -%>
<%= text_field_tag "new_receipt[]", nil, id: "new_receipt_2" -%>
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more automated approach.

Comment: Just curious, why are you submitting an array of text in one param?

Comment: The form holds a table and the user can add/remove rows dynamically.  I don't know ahead of time how many rows there will be.  Submitting arrays is the easiest was to get data to the server and work with the data once it gets to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a third argument to the [`text_field_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag) helper:

```
text_field_tag 'new_receipt[]', nil, id: 'some_html_id'
text_field_tag 'new_receipt[]', nil, id: 'some_other_html_id'
```

There is no "automated" approach unless you respect the uniqueness of the names in a HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

Not really more automated, but more programmatic:

```
<% 2.times do |i| %>
  <%= text_field_tag "new_receipt[]", nil, id: "new_receipt_#{i+1}" %>
<% end -%>
```